# Can't Change layout in Custom Joomla 3 Component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-component

I'm trying to get my Joomla 3 component to render the layout specified in the url but I can't figure out why it insists on displaying the **test.php** layout. All relevant code below and the url I'm using is:

mysite.com/index.php?option=com_test&controller=test&layout=test2

Maybe I'm doing this completely wrong but here's my code so far:

**Code:**

joomla/components/com_test/test.php :

```
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport( 'joomla.session.session' );
JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT.'/tables');
JLoader::registerPrefix('Test', JPATH_COMPONENT);
TestHelpersAssets::load();
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$controller = $app->input->get('controller','default');
$classname = 'TestControllers'.ucwords($controller);
$controller = new $classname();
$controller->execute();
```

joomla/components/com_test/controllers/test.php :

```
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' ); 

class TestControllersTest extends JControllerBase
{
  public function execute()
  {

    $app = $this->getApplication();
    $document = JFactory::getDocument();

    $viewName = $app->input->getWord('view', 'test');       
    $viewFormat = $document->getType();     //html, raw etc.
    $layoutName = $app->input->getWord('layout', 'test2');

    $app->input->set('view', $viewName);

    // Register the layout paths for the view
    $paths = new SplPriorityQueue;
    $paths->insert(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/views/' . $viewName . '/tmpl', 'normal');

    $viewClass  = 'TestViews' . ucfirst($viewName) . ucfirst($viewFormat);
    $modelClass = 'TestModels' . ucfirst($viewName);

    $view = new $viewClass(new $modelClass, $paths);

    $view->setLayout($layoutName);

    echo $view->render();

    return true;
  }

}
```

joomla/components/com_test/models/test.php :

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' ); 

class TestModelsTest extends JModelBase
{

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct(); 
  }

}
```

joomla/components/com_test/views/test/html.php :

```
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' ); 

class TestViewsTestHtml extends JViewHtml
{
  function render()
  {
    return parent::render();
  }
}
```

joomla/components/com_test/views/test/tmpl/test.php :

```
<h1>This is the test layout for the test view</h1>
```

joomla/components/com_test/views/test/tmpl/test2.php :

```
<h1>This is the test2 layout for the test view</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Joomla doesn't like numbers in the layout names... I changed test2.php to testtwo.php and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

In the new mvc the folder names like model, view, controller are expected to be singular (unlike old mvc which expece models, views, controllers). Likewise your classnames should have singular segments.